# How do you pass an Error to os_log from Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, logging

I am trying to log an error from a catch block. The documentations says the following:

> To format a log message, use a standard NSString or printf format string
>
> In addition to standard format string specifiers, such as %@ and %d, the logging system supports custom decoding of values by denoting value types inline in the format %{value_type}d. In addition, the specifier %.*P can be used to decode arbitrary binary data. The system includes a number of built-in value type decoders, shown in Table 3.
>
> errno %{errno}d Broken pipe

When I do this I get an error:

```
import os.log

do {
    try throwError()
} catch {
    os_log("Error: %{errno}d", log: .default, type: .error, error)
}
```

However the compiler outputs errors with:

> Argument type 'Error' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'

Is there a better way than passing `error.localizedDescription` as the argument?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `@` instead of `d` and convert the error into a String

```
os_log("Error: %@", log: .default, type: .error, String(describing: error))
```

Comment: Is there any need to leave {errno} in the formatting then, if the argument is just a plain string instead of an error?

Comment: Just tried it, and with {errno} included I get the following in the log: "Error: <decode: mismatch for [%{errno}@] got [OBJECT private sz:58]>".

Comment: @Doug Sorry, that was a copy/paste error from me. errno should not be in the string

Comment: Thanks @Joakim. Also I've had a bit of a search and realised that errno is for C errors and not (NS)Errors, which is where I was getting confused.